# Como faço para por uma imagem de fundo no CSS usando o PHP?

Tags: php, html, css, mysqli, img

Eu estou tentando por uma imagem de fundo pelo css usando o PHP, ou seja a imagem que quero por de fundo está dentro do banco. Eu abro as tags php dentro do URL do background

```
 background-image:  url(?php echo $top['ft_feature']; ?>);
```

O código que uso para que o banco ache a imagem é esse:

```
  $consulta3 = "SELECT * FROM feature";
  $con3 = $mysqli->query($consulta3) or die (@mysqli_error());
```

E o código que eu coloco em

```
background: url()
```

como eu disse é esse:

```
echo $top['ft_feature'];
```

Eu queria saber se tem algum jeito de por ele como background usando a imagem que eu selecionei do banco.

Comment: Quando vc diz css, vc quer dizer o arquivo css ou um bloco style dentro de uma página php?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tem como sim Vinicius,

mas lembre que o código php deverá ficar dentro de um arquivo '.php' para que seja interpretado pelo servidor, caso esteja tentando colocar o código php dentro do arquivo'.css' não ira funcionar pois o servidor não vai interpretar.

dentro do arquivo '.php' você pode colocar o código php dentro da sua tag, assim:

```
<div style="background-image: url('<?php echo $top['ft_feature']; ?>')">
```

Nesse exemplo usei a tag div você colocará a sua tag.

Ainda dentro do arquivo '.php' você também pode usar o seu código php em um bloco de estilos, assim:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
        .exemplo {
            background-image: url("<?php echo $top['ft_feature']; ?>")
        }
        <style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="exemplo">
        ...
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

*Há um erro de sintax na sua pergunta, falta um '<' na abertura do bloco php e o bloco tem que estar entre aspas seguindo a sintax do css: background-image: url(' ')

Comment: <body background="<?php echo $top['ft_feature']; ?>">

Comment: Olá, muito obrigado pela resposta, funcionou perfeitamente, agora quando eu adiciono o link do poster, ele mostra o que está no banco, valeu mesmo

Comment: Não precisa agradecer Vinicius, apenas marque minha resposta como a correta clicando no check (sinal de certo) do lado esquerdo da resposta